# Why is my code only working on part of my image?

Tags: python, loops, image-processing

I created code to equalize the luminosity values of pixels in an image so that when the image is further edited I do not have dark or light spots in my final image. However, the code seems to stop short and only equalize part of my image. Any ideas as to why the code is stopping early?

**Here is my code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('EXP_0159-2_8b.tif')
imgOut = img.copy()

for i in range(0, len(img[0, :])):
    imgLine1 = (img[:, i] < 165) * img[:, i]
    p = imgLine1.nonzero()
    if len(p[0]) < 1:
        imgOut[:, i] == 0
    else:
        imgLine2 = imgLine1[p[0]]
        def curvefitting(lineFunction):
            x = np.arange(0, len(lineFunction))
            y = lineFunction
            curve = np.polyfit(x, y, deg = 2)
            a = curve[0]
            b = curve[1]
            c = curve[2]
            curveEquation = (a*(x**2)) + (b*(x**1)) + (c) 
            curveCorrected = lineFunction - curveEquation + 200
            return curveCorrected
        imgLine1[p[0]] = curvefitting(imgLine2)
        imgOut[:, i] = imgLine1

plt.imshow(imgOut, cmap = 'gray')
```

The for loop takes the individual columns of pixels in my image and restricts the endpoints of that column to (0, 165), so that pixels outside of that range are turned into zero and ignored by the nonzero() function. The if condition just finalizes the conversion of values outside (0, 165) to zero. Additionally, I converted the image to gray so I would not have to deal with colors and could focus only on luminosity.

[This is my corrected image. The program works to average the luminosity values across the entire surface. However, you can see that it stops before reaching the end.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlEJ4.png) The initial image was darker on the sides and lighter in the middle, but the file is too large to upload.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can maybe share the original via Dropbox or Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in color you can convert input image to grayscale. That would simplified the matrix multiplications. The simplified version would be

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg



def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])

def curvefitting(lineFunction):
    x = np.arange(0, len(lineFunction))
    y = lineFunction
    curve = np.polyfit(x, y, deg = 2)
    a = curve[0]
    b = curve[1]
    c = curve[2]
    curveEquation = [(a*(x_**2)) + (b*(x_**1)) + (c) for x_ in x]
    curveCorrected = lineFunction - curveEquation + 200
    return curveCorrected

img = mpimg.imread('EXP_0159-2_8b.tif')
img = rgb2gray(img)
imgOut = img.copy()



for i in range(0, len(img[0, :])):
    imgLine1 = (img[:, i] < 165) * img[:, i]
    p = imgLine1.nonzero()
    if len(p) < 1:
        imgOut[:, i] == 0
    else:
        imgLine2 = imgLine1[p]
        imgLine1[p] = curvefitting(imgLine2)
        imgOut[:, i] = imgLine1

plt.imshow(imgOut, cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
```